# Progress Reporting from an Async method in a Windows 8 Store App

Tags: c#, windows-8, progress-bar, winrt-xaml, async-await

In a Windows 8 Style app, I have the following code which is retrieving a list of files in a custom FileService. This is being fired in the Constructor of a ViewModel.

```
private async void Construct()
{
   Files = new ObservableCollection<FileViewModel>();
   IList _files = await _fileRepository.GetFiles();
   foreach (File file in _files)
   {
      Files.Add(new FileViewModel(file));
   }
}
```

It works perfectly, but what I am struggling to figure out is how I would perform Progress reporting on this to inform the user that something is happening while the files are being loaded.

Looking at it, I would like to have a bool IsBusy property which I could bind to something like a ProgressRing on the View. I get that I could set to this to true when the process starts but how can I get a Completed callback from operation where I could then set this property to False?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, I think you shouldn't use `async void` methods (unless they are event handlers, of course). "Asynchronous constructors" are best implemented as a static `async` factory method or with [asynchronous lazy initialization](http://nitoprograms.blogspot.com/2012/08/asynchronous-lazy-initialization.html) (explained on my blog). Both of these approaches are better than `async void`.

Now, on to progress reporting. The [Task-based Asynchronous Programming](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=19957) document describes the recommended way of reporting progress, and my [AsyncEx](http://nitoasyncex.codeplex.com/) library includes an `IProgress<T>` implementation called `PropertyProgress` specifically for treating progress updates as ViewModel observable properties.

However, it sounds like you just need a "busy indicator", not a full "progress report". This is quite a bit simpler:

```
private async Task Construct()
{
  Files = new ObservableCollection<FileViewModel>();
  IsBusy = true;
  IList _files = await _fileRepository.GetFiles();
  IsBusy = false;
  foreach (File file in _files)
  {
    Files.Add(new FileViewModel(file));
  }
}
```

In this example, I'm assuming that the `IsBusy` setter will raise `INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged` appropriately.